# Literature on reaction diffusion equations

Tags: reference-request, ap.analysis-of-pdes, mathematical-modeling, epidemics-modeling

My research area is age structure modelling, basically when applied to reaction diffusion equations. We mainly discuss the existence of travelling wave solutions; I want to work on the stability of travelling wave solutions.

Where should I read about this topic and how should I proceed? I am totally stuck.

Comment: Such matters are best discussed with your research mentor, who normally is an expert and knows the context. If a mentor isn't an expert, as may happen if you picked the topic yourself, then the fact that you are "totally stuck" suggests you may be better off switching to a project within mentor's expertise.

Answer (score 2):

As stated by Igor Belegradek in [his comment above](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/422950/literature-on-reaction-diffusion-equations#comment1086943_422950), the first thing to do is to search for an expert advice. However, an expert advice is sometimes hard to find, for example if you work in a big firm and you work on a research project involving strict confidentiality policies. Therefore a reference is useful, at least to see what kind of research have been done on the topic of interest: and, on the theory of traveling waves in for reaction diffusion equations, my advice is to have a look at the  the monograph [1]. It is a really wonderful work as it details the theory and the history of the topic: written by chemical engineers highly skilled in mathematics, it is still a true reference, despite being written nearly 28 years ago.

**Reference**

[1] Aizik Isaakovich Vol’pert, Vitaly Aizikovich Vol’pert, Vladimir Aizikovich Vol’pert, *[Traveling wave solutions of parabolic systems](https://books.google.com/books?id=1qP--BRsLAwC&lpg=PP1&hl=it&pg=PP1#v=onepage&q&f=true)*, (English) Translations of Mathematical Monographs, 140. Providence, RI: American Mathematical Society. xii, 448 p. (1994), [MR1297766](https://mathscinet.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=MR1297766), [Zbl 1001.35060](https://zbmath.org/?q=an%3A1001.35060).